# VS 2012 Database no longer working after opening in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a database that I have been working with in Visual Studio 2012.  I had opened the database user SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2012 so that I could backup the database.  After backing up the database, I detached it from SQL Server Management Studio.  Now I can not get the database to open in Visual Studio 2012.  I get the following message:

The database 'H:\PBC\PBCSITE2012\APP_DATA\PBCDATA.MDF' cannot be opened because it is   version 706. This server supports version 662 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'H:\PBC\PBCSITE2012\APP_DATA\PBCDATA.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file H:\PBC\PBCSite2012\App_Data\PBCData.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Any ideas on what I did to cause this or what I can do to repair it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 706 is a database file from Sql Server 2012
Version 665 is a database file from Sql Server 2008R2 (post SP1 ?)

You are attempting to open a later version of the database file than the current server version ( for example using 2008 r2 to open a 2012 database)

Check your connection strings to verify that connection is being made to the correct instance of the database server.

Comment: I am trying to connect to the same database using the same connection that I had always used in Visual Studio 2012.  I detached the database file from VS 2012 so that I could open it in SQL Server Management Studio so I could back it up.  I then detached the file from SQL Server Management Studio.  I understand that 706 is from Sql Server 2012 and 665 is from Sql Server 2008R2, but the file is exactly the same that I have been using all along.  So did opening the file in Sql Server Management Studio cause the file to change?

Comment: Okay, it is working again.  I played around with the connection and got it to work.  I am not sure exactly what I did, but changing the datasource from SQLEXPRESS to (LocalDB)\v11.0 seemed to correct the problem.

Comment: Sql express is odder localdb is newer that is used by default with vs 2012.